# Delphi's LongRec() func in c++

Tags: c++, delphi

I'm rewriting code from Delphi to C++ and here's a line I can't translate:

```
typedef vector<char> ByteArray;

unsigned char Bytes[4];

Buf[sCP + J] = LongRec( R ).Bytes[3 - I];
```

sCP, J, R and I variables are Ints.

Google says *"LongRec declares a record that stores the various parts of the specified value as type Word or Byte."* but I still can't understand how to make it work in C++

Comment: Basically, it typecasts `int32` to `int8[4]` and reads an element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C++, you would use a union, but note that getting anything else out as you put in is undefined behaviour. It will **probably** work the same way as in Delphi, but only on the same platform, i.e. with the same [ABI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface) as Win32 or Win64, depending on the compiler target used in Delphi.

So in Delphi:

```
type
  LongRec = packed record
    case Integer of
      0: (Lo, Hi: Word);
      1: (Words: array [0..1] of Word);
      2: (Bytes: array [0..3] of Byte);
  end;
```

And "literal" C++ translation:

```
#pragma pack(push, 1)
union LongRec
{
     struct { unsigned short Lo, Hi; };
     struct { unsigned short Words[2]; };
     struct { unsigned char Bytes[4]; };
}
#pragma pack(pop)
```

*(The above assumes that `sizeof(short) == 2`, that variables are little-endian and that the structs completely overlap, all of which may not be the case for all platforms.)*

But again, if you want to read the second to highest byte of a `long` and do something like

```
byte2 = reinterpret_cast<LongRec *>(&myLongint)->Bytes[2];
```

that is **undefined behaviour** *(although it will **probably** work on the same Windows platform as Delphi)*.

The proper behaviour is (slower, but correct):

```
byte2 = myLongint >> 16 & 0xFF;
```

or

```
myHiWord = myLongint >> 16 & 0xFFFF;
```

But even that assumes that a byte is an octet, which is not always the case. In other words, this is not portable, and will only work *as is* on Windows 32 and 64 bit.

Comment: The correct translation would include a `#pragma pack(1)` on the `union` declaration, and then the `reinterpret_cast` would have to be used like this: `byte2 = reinterpret_cast<LongRec&>(myLongint).Bytes[2];`, or this: `byte2 = reinterpret_cast<LongRec*>(&myLongint)->Bytes[2];`